# Using CDN Networks for e-commerce site

Tags: apache, e-commerce, cdn

Can an e-commerce site working within a country use CDN networks to reduce the proximity of visitors from various cities to the server, while the server is also located within the same country?

Comment: Are you asking about building a CDN to distribute the e-commerce site or are you talking about writing the markup for the site to include assets like a JavaScript library (eg. jQuery) and a CSS framework (eg. Bootstrap) from the vendor's CDN?

Comment: What does the question really have to do with Apache? CDN is usually not even in your infrastructure network.

Answer (score 1):

A CDN is a geographically distributed network of proxy servers and their data centres. How the severs are distributed is decided based on the goal which is to distribute service spatially relative to end-users.

So the answer is yes, if a service has many customers within a country, creating a CDN with servers in each major city would probably help.